# 2018 AMC 12A-Cyclic Quadrilaterals

Tags: contest-math

Triangle $ABC$ is an isosceles right triangle with $AB=AC=3$. Let $M$ be the midpoint of hypotenuse $\overline{BC}$. Points $I$ and $E$ lie on sides $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{AB}$, respectively, so that $AI>AE$ and $AIME$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. Given that triangle $EMI$ has area $2$, the length $CI$ can be written as $\frac{a-\sqrt{b}}{c}$, where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive integers and $b$ is not divisible by the square of any prime. What is the value of $a+b+c$?
How do we prove that triangle EMI is isosceles. Currently, I know that angle EMI is a right angle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that $\triangle EMI$ is isosceles, namely $IM = EM$, is a direct consequence of the fact that $\angle EMI = 90^\circ$ and $M$ is the midpoint of $\overline{BC}$.  To see this, all one needs to do is consider a rotation of the entire figure about point $M$ by $90$ degrees, either clockwise or counterclockwise.  Doing so will identify $\triangle AMB$ with $\triangle AMC$; moreover, it also identifies $E$ with $I$, since $\angle EMI = 90^\circ$ as previously stated.  Hence $IM = EM$ as claimed.